# cordova iframe violates the following Content Security

Tags: cordova

In my index.html, I try to put an iframe

```
<iframe src="http://www.example.com" style="width:100%;min-height: 320px"></iframe>
```

Hower I got that message:

> Refused to frame 'http://www.example.com/' because it violates the
>   following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data:
>   gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'frame-src' was
>   not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

I tried to fix it with some meta:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' www.example.com">
```

Still the same error

Answer (score 2):

**Remove meta** "Content-Security-Policy" **OR**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; frame-src * ;">
```

For more details, see this post..

[Cordova White List Plugin](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/index.html)